# Reading out internal memory from Polar H10 with Android

Tags: android, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, android-bluetooth

I own a Polar H10 device and I'm interested in the raw data (r-r intervals). There are som open source Android apps for retrieving such raw data at realtime using BLE (e.g. https://github.com/mobilars/BLEConnect or https://github.com/simonkamronn/Polar-H7-Recorder).

The H10 has internal memory. How can I read out this internal memory after a training session with Android? I would really appreciate if there is some example code or explanations.

Comment: There is no standard for this.  The RR interval data in real time there is a standard for so you just follow the standard and it works.  For accessing the raw memory if it's possible at all you need to ask Polar for the details.

Comment: @Ifor I have written Polar and they said that there is no possibility for accessing memory. Which standard do you mean for the RR interval? By the way, do you know how to do correction of the intervals? I've just read that this is necessary but I don't know how to do it.

Comment: The Bluetooth low energy heart rate standard.  Some details at https://www.bluetooth.com/specifications/gatt/viewer?attributeXmlFile=org.bluetooth.service.heart_rate.xml